# XPath how to search for a string iphone

Tags: xcode, parsing, ios4, xpath, html-parsing

I'm using hpple to parse content from a html page. I want to find the string 'Course Content' and select the paragraph after it. How is this possible?

At present i have this code which return the paragraph at index 0 however its not good enough.

Thanks for any help ..

Comment: Dear me.  More info is needed.  First of all, what is `xpathParser1`?  Can you post your code for that class?

Comment: I'm using the hpple parser.I didn't paste the code in the first instance because i believe its irelevant i just want to know the syntax for xpath on how to search for a particular string and then result paragraphs from that point onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/html/body
     /div[@id='wrap']
     /div[@id='inner']
     /div[@id='content']
     /div[@id='main-content']
     /div[@id='content_div_16973']
     /h3[.='Course Content']/following-sibling::p[1]
```